# Почему вначале ASCII код элемента один, а в конце кода другой?

Tags: c, строки, ascii

Вот мой код. Вначале кода я проверяю какому числу соответствует каждая буква русского алфавита. Выходят числа от -32 до -1 для а...я и от -64 до -33 для А...Я. После хочу с этим работать и выходит ошибка. Проверяю в конце кода какому числу соответствуют те же буквы и там уже, например, для а -95, для б -94 и тд.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    char alp[100] = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьюэя";
    char alp1[100] = "АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
    //for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++){
        //printf("%c - %d\n", alp[i], (int)(alp[i]));
    //}
    char str[100];
    gets(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if((int)(str[i]) > -32 && (int)(str[i]) < -1)
        {
            str[i] = (char)((int)(str[i]) - 32);
        }
    }
    puts(str);
    printf("%d", (int)(str[0]));
}
```

Comment: Как это воспроизвести? У меня, например, не получается... Дайте такой код, чтоб это было точно видно.

Comment: Исходный код в кодировке Windows-1251, а консоль в CP866???

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    char alp[100] = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьюэя";
    for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++){
        printf("%c - %d\n", alp[i], (int)(alp[i]));
    }
    char str[100];
    gets(str);
    puts(str);
    printf("%d", (int)(str[0]));
}`
вот код. 
при вводе символ б, выводится -95, хотя только что числу б соответствовало -31

Comment: Подождите, вы пишете "Проверяю в конце кода какому числу соответствуют ***те же буквы***" — но вы же проверяете ***совсем другие***! Я вас понял так, что у вас в `alp` сначала одни коды, потом другие. А сравнивать мягкое с теплым... Разные кодировки, что вы хотите...

Comment: т.е вы хотите сказать, что буква б в строке с алфавитом и буква б, которую я ввожу потом в консоли это разные буквы? а почему так происходит, почему у них кодировки разные?

Comment: Когда вы сохраняете файл с исходным кодом программы, текстовый редактор, встречая символ `б`, пишет в файл байт со значением `-31`. Когда вы вводите в консоли символ `б`, она отправляет в поток ввода вашей программы байт со значением `-95`. Так сложилось исторически.